# Changed matrix dimensions - now formula doesnt work. Related to computer science

Tags: matrices, computer-science

I'm writing a computer code to solve a problem, and I ran into some difficulties. This is not a coding question, my problem is purely mathematical, I will explain.

We have a matrix $M\in Mat(\mathbb R)_{n\times n}$ such that the first 2 diagonals have non zero values as entries, and everything else is zero.

We fill the upper half of the matrix except for the 2 given diagonals (meaning $i+2\leq j$) with the following formula:

$M_{i,j}=\max(a+\min(M_{i+2,j},M_{i+1,j-1}), b+\min(M_{i+1,j-1},M_{i,j-2}))$

where $a,b$ are some given numbers. You can see that in order to compute the $k$th diagonal, we need to have the $k-2$ diagonal. Since we were given the first $2$, we can fill the upper half of the matrix. This results in an upper triangular matrix.

Now, for reasons of computer science and conserving memory, I don't want to allocate an entire matrix. Think of each of these entries as something you pay for. In the above notation, we paid for $n^2$ entries but used only half.

So to solve this, I defined a new matrix. Such that the first row has $n$ entries, the second row has $n-1$, and so on. Generally speaking, the $i$th row has $n-i$ elements. In computer science this is called a jagged array.

But since we changed the dimensions of the matrix, the formula has to change as well. We essentially moved every element $i$ columns to the left ($i$ starts at zero.). So we should have $M_{i,j}=M'_{i,j-i}$ where $M'$ is the new jagged array, and so the formula above will become:

$M'_{i,j}=\max(a+\min(M'_{i+2,j-i},M'_{i+1,j-1-i}), b+\min(M'_{i+1,j-1-i},M'_{i,j-2-i}))$

But for some reason, this formula does not work. I'll show an example. Suppose we have $a=47$ and $b=26$ and:

$M=\begin{pmatrix}47 & 47 & x\\0 & 45 & 45 \\0 & 0 & 26\end{pmatrix}$ And we want to find $x$ using the formula above for non jagged matrices:

$x=M_{0,2}=\max(47+\min(M_{2,2},M_{1,1}),26+\min(M_{1,1},M_{0,0}))=\max(47+\min(26,45),26+\min(26,47))=\max(47+26,26+26)=47+26=73$

So $x=73$. But you will see now that if we do this with a jagged array, the jagged array formula will not work. To create the jagged array, we will shift the entries of row $i$, $i$ columns to the left:

$M'=\begin{pmatrix}47 & 47 & x\\45 & 45 \\26\end{pmatrix}$.

We want to calculate $x$ with the jagged array formula:
$x=M'_{0,2}=\max(47+\min(M'_{2,2},M'_{1,1}),26+\min(M'_{1,1},M'_{0,0}))$

But the entry $M'_{2,2}$ does not exist! So our formula after the change to smaller matrix dimensions was incorrect!

I need help fixing the formula please, I don't know where is the mistake.

Comment: Actually, that is also not good. Since to calculate $M'_{1,2}$ for example, we need to compute $M'_{1+2,2-(1+2)}=M'_{3,-1}$ which does not exist. your formula seems to work when $M$ is $3\times 3$ but not on more then that.

Comment: you meant "so now you need to have $M'_{i,j-i}$, right? Sorry, I don't get it. We had $M_{i,j}=\max(a+\min(M_{i+2,j},M_{i+1,j-1}), b+\min(M_{i+1,j-1},M_{i,j-2}))$. So surely if $M_{i,j}=M'_{i,j-i}$ then $M'_{i,j-i}=\max(a+\min(M'_{i+2,j-(i+2)},M'_{i+1,j-1-(i+1)}), b+\min(M'_{i+1,j-1-(i+1)},M'_{i,j-2-i}))$.

Comment: Managed to solve it! It was not trivial at all. The key thing to understand is that in our first matrix $M$ we computed through the diagonals. In $M'$ we compute the columns. the $k$th diagonal of $M$ is actually the $k$th column of $M'$. So the incrementation of $i$ and $j$ is different. and the correct formula is $M'_{i,j}=\max(a+\min(M'_{i+2,j-2},M'_{i+1,j-2}),b+\min(M'_{i+2,j-2},M'_{i,j-2}))$